# How to allow UTF-8 data in request received from Facelets page

Tags: jsf, utf-8, jboss, facelets, jboss7.x

I am using JBoss AS 7. I created a Facelets page which is bound to a managed bean. I have JSF input text field in my page. If I write some special characters in input text field and submit the page, then it send a request to server. But special characters are already converted to some other characters. I added UTF-8 support tag in Facelets page, but I am still not getting UTF-8 data on server side. Do I need to add some settings on JBoss server so that it can accept UTF-8 data?

i Added a simple Text field

`<h:inputText value="#{myBean.value}" />`

and wrote text like this
`"“ ©” ‘with special character’ — » É €"`

i added a breakpoint on server and examined the value and i am getting something like this

`Ã¢ÂÂ ÃÂ©Ã¢ÂÂ Ã¢ÂÂwith special characterÃ¢ÂÂ Ã¢ÂÂ ÃÂ» ÃÂ Ã¢ÂÂ¬`

I don't know how to get actual value on the server side

Comment: Please describe the problem symtoms in more detail. What exactly did you submit and how exactly are you checking them (e.g. by printing to `System.out` and then reading in log file (where?), or by checking the individual characters in a loop, or by saving in DB and then checking in there (which? how? where?), or by  writing to txt file and then opening it (how? where?), etc) and to which characters exactly are they been converted, etc. In the meanwhile, go through http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html to understand the world of bytes and chars better.

Comment: I think its more related to how you are reading data on server rather than how your JSF page is sending it.. 

can you put a debug point on bean on setter of `myBean.setValue()` and see what value is being set and update the question ??

Comment: You are still not clear on where exactly you're seeing Mojibake. Do you see it in IDE debugger variables view? Or do you see it in IDE console after System.out.println()? Or do you see it in some specific DB admin tool after saving in DB? etc...etc... You seem to still not have read the aforelinked article.  I strongly recommend to do so before we waste more time. You need to understand that there are so many places where byte-character conversions take place and that you should absolutely be specific in identifying the place causing the conversion fail.